# Como convertir una lista de objetos a String separado por comas en Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, programación-funcional

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar un atributo de un objeto en específico y construir un string separado por comas en Kotlin?

Ejemplo:

```
data class Usuario(
  var nombre,
  var apellido,
  var edad
)
```

`{Usuario: Juan, Apellido: Perez, Edad:44}
{Usuario: Fernando, Apellido: Posas, Edad:13}
{Usuario: Jose, Apellido: Fernandez, Edad:24}`

Si quiero separar los nombres, la salida sería:

```
Juan,Fernando,Jose
```

Comment: Hola agreguendos formas como ouedes realizar esto en Kotlin, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo solucioné utilizando la función [joinToString](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) de Kotlin, de la siguiente manera:

```
        val listaUsuarios = listOf(Usuario("Juan","Perez",44),
                Usuario("Fernando","Posas",13),
                Usuario("Jose","Fernandez",24))
        print(listaUsuarios.joinToString(separator = ",", transform = { it.nombre }))
```

Comment: Perfecta solución, recuerda marcar tu respuesta como aceptada, que te lo has ganado tú solito :)

Comment: Muchas gracias @DavidDPG, muy amable.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero dos opciones, la primera obteniendo en un loop la propiedad `nombre` de cada objeto y almacenando el valor en un `StringBuilder`:

```
  val listaUsuarios = listOf(Usuario("Juan","Perez",44),
      Usuario("Fernando","Posas",13),
      Usuario("Jose","Fernandez",24))

  val usuarios = StringBuilder();

  var count: Int? = 0
  for(usuario in listaUsuarios){
     usuarios.append("${usuario.nombre}");
     if (count != listaUsuarios.count() - 1) {
        usuarios.append(", ");
        count= count?.inc()        
     }
  }    

   println(usuarios)
```

salida:

```
Juan, Fernando, Jose
```

[Demo online](https://pl.kotl.in/wSqHXmOoi)

---

Otra forma se realiza utilizando [joinToString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html)

> [joinToString()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) Crea una cadena de todos los elementos separados
>   usando el separador y usando el prefijo y el postfijo dados si se
>   suministran.

```
  val listaUsuarios = listOf(Usuario("Juan","Perez",44),
      Usuario("Fernando","Posas",13),
      Usuario("Jose","Fernandez",24))

   val usuarios = listaUsuarios.joinToString(separator = ",", transform = { it.nombre })   
   println("usuarios : " + usuarios)
```

salida:

```
Juan, Fernando, Jose
```

**[Demo online](https://pl.kotl.in/XEM9WySXz)**